# pandas - combine time and date from two dataframe columns to a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

This is a follow up question of the accepted solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576910/convert-columns-with-time-format-hhmmss-to-sec).

I have a pandas dataframe:

In one column 'time' is the time stored in the following format: '`HHMMSS`' (e.g. 203412 means 20:34:12).

In another column 'date' the date is stored in the following format: '`YYmmdd`' (e.g 200712 means 2020-07-12). `YY` represents the addon to the year 2000.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'time': ['123455', '000010', '100000'],
        'date': ['200712', '210601', '190610']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

#     time    date
#0  123455  200712
#1  000010  210601
#2  100000  190610
```

I need a third column which contains the combined datetime format (e.g. `2020-07-12 12:34:55`) of the two other columns. So far, I can only modify the time but I do not know how to add the date.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H%M%S')

print(df)

#     time    date            datetime
#0  123455  200712 1900-01-01 12:34:55
#1  000010  210601 1900-01-01 00:00:10
#2  100000  190610 1900-01-01 10:00:00
```

How can I add in column `df['datetime']` the date from column `df['date']`, so that the dataframe is:

```
     time    date            datetime
0  123455  200712 2020-07-12 12:34:55
1  000010  210601 2021-06-01 00:00:10
2  100000  190610 2019-06-10 10:00:00
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073155/combine-date-column-and-time-column-into-datetime), but I am not exactly sure how to use it for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join columns first and then specify formar:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'], format='%y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(df)
     time    date            datetime
0  123455  200712 2020-07-12 12:34:55
1  000010  210601 2021-06-01 00:00:10
2  100000  190610 2019-06-10 10:00:00
```

If possible integer columns:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + df['time'].astype(str), format='%y%m%d%H%M%S')
```